Google Places throws error: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
I am attempting to use the Google Places API to use within my app. So far, I have gone through the entirety of the Google Places API Documentation exactly, found here, and have not made any progress.
The error I am receiving is: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
This is my implementation for my places dependency, with everything else removed. If I comment out this line, everything else works perfectly fine as per this suggestion which specifies that one of my packages is not resolving. I have commented out other recent dependencies to see if there were any conflicting packages, this is not the case. It is also not a case of version mismatch, per this solution as I manage that in my libs.versions.toml file and keep everything up-to-date.
    dependencies {
        implementation(libs.libraries.places)
    }

which points to
[versions]
places = "3.4.0"

[libraries]
places = { group = "com.google.android.libraries.places", name = "places", version.ref = "places" }

In my project SDKs, I have Google Play services enabled in my SDK tools.
My project-level build.gradle.kts file includes the gradle secrets plugin as required by Google to function as well as including maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }, per this solution, which is addressed as well in my libs.versions.toml file. I have read other StackOverflow solutions to this issue as being resolved with toggling offline mode, as well as making sure that google is called before mavencentral in my settings.gradle.kts file.
In attempting to clean and rebuild my project with the repository still referenced and not commented out, I receive the following 13 errors, all pointing to not being able to find the google places package:
FAILURE: Build completed with 13 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.libraries:places:places.


Any insight into what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

For anyone else coming here because of the Google Documentation, the documentation shows that the import should come from "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.4.0", however, the real working import is from "com.google.maps.android:places-ktx:3.4.0".
I trusted the import to be the only thing that wouldn't be an issue from the Google Documentation, however, this was the only thing wrong with it.
